# How to show $13\left(x^{2}+1\right)+\sqrt{2\left(x^{4}+1\right)}+62 x-\frac{45\left(x^{2}-1\right)}{\ln x}>0$ for $x\in(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I am doing a problem that can be reduced to proving the following inequality:

> $$13\left(x^{2}+1\right)+\sqrt{2\left(x^{4}+1\right)}+62 x-\frac{45\left(x^{2}-1\right)}{\ln x}>0, x \in(0,1)
> $$

But I don't know how to handle it. 
I tried to separate $\ln x$ from the function，because it is easier to differentiate. But I cannot handle the radical expression.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried something? Please show your own thought and working out so far :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried? Please edit your question to include anything you have attempted. If you haven't done any work yet, please do some and edit your question accordingly. Your question will be much better received this way.

Comment: I have turned the orgianal question to this one,easier than that before.I tried to separate “lnx” from the function，because it is easier to derivate.Then I cannot solve a great number of radical expression.

Comment: I want to post my picture of its anaylsis,but I do not have enough reputation...My English is very poor,sorry about that...

Comment: I think the infinimum of the expression is zero; in other words it gets arbitrarily close to $0$ but never exactly zero.

Comment: By the way have you tried putting in a link of the picture you wanted to put in?

Comment: My friend has solved the problem,and it's very beautiful!

Comment: My picture cannot be pasted,confused...The question has been solved ,and thanks to all of you!!!

Comment: Use [Imgur](https://imgur.com) to upload your image of your attempt and put a link to it in your question. But for subsequent questions learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Ok,I'll learn to use MathJax soon~

Comment: @苏承心: Can you post your original problem that leads you to this inequality?

Comment: I hope OP will come back to post his/her friend's beautiful solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here's my sketch proof:**

For the following assume $x\in(0,1)$. First use the following lemma:

> $$\left(x^2+1\right)+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{x^4+1}>2x+2\left(\frac{x^4+1}{x^2+1}\right)$$

*Proof:*
$${\frac{d}{dx}\left(2(x^4+1)-\left\{2x+2\left(\frac{x^4+1}{x^2+1}\right)-(x^2+1)\right\}^2\right)\\=\frac{4(x-1)^5(x^4+2x^3+4x^2+4x+1)}{(x^2+1)^3}<0}$$
So plugging in $x=1$ to the original gives $4=4$ and we're done.

Then it remains to show that

> $$12\left(x^2+1\right)+2\left(\frac{x^4+1}{x^2+1}\right)+64x>45\left(\frac{x^2-1}{\ln
> x}\right)$$

*Proof:* By algebraic manipulation, this is equivalent to 
$$\frac{2}{45}\ln x<\frac{x^4-1}{7x^4+32x^3+12x^2+32x+7}$$
So 
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{2}{45}\ln x-\frac{x^4-1}{7x^4+32x^3+12x^2+32x+7}\right)\\[5px]=\frac{2(x-1)^6(49x^2+22x+49)}{45x(7x^4+32x^3+12x^2+32x+7)^2}>0$$
and plugging in $x=1$ to the equivalent form gives $0=0$ and we're done.

Answer (score 0):

$x \in(0,1)$ so

\begin{align}
13(x^{2}+1)&>0\\
\sqrt{2(x^{4}+1)}&>0\\
62 x&>0\\
-\frac{45(x^{2}-1)}{\ln x}&>0
\end{align}

Comment: The last one is not correct,The inequality is very "tight"...

Comment: it is correct because 0<x<1 so (x^2-1)<0 and always ln x >0

Comment: It is not correct, since $\ln x <0$ for $0<x<1.$

Comment: oh you are right

Comment: So now the overall situation is that all the terms except the last one, are positive ...

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that

$$\lim_{x\to  0}\frac{x^2-1}{\ln x}=0$$

now you should prove:

$$\lim_{x\to  1^-}\frac{x^2-1}{\ln x}=2^-$$
(use Hopital rule)

So:

$$13\Big((1)^{2}+1\Big)+\sqrt{2\Big((1)^{4}+1\Big)}+62(1)-{45}(2^-)>0$$

Comment: I want to prove the inequality,not the limitation hhh

Comment: show $\frac{x^2-1}{\ln x}$ is strictly increasing function  and then with the 
 limitation show the suprimum is 2 when $x \in(0,1)$